# How is .row class defined in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I searched `.row` in bootstrap.css file I got the following definitions:

```
...
.row:before,
.row:after,
... {
  display: table;
  content: " ";
}

...
.row:after  
... {
  clear: both;
}
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

With these definitions I expect the `.row` class to behave as following:

- Before and after any row there should be block level element encompassing one white space . The white space before `.row` should not be *cleared* and the white space after `.row.` should  be *cleared*. -- None of this happen actually.
- Any `div` element with class `.row` should spread 15px out of its containing element to both left and right. -- This is observable with usual containing divs but not with body element. E.g. if there are two divs woth class row inside the `body` element:

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css");  

 .row div:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: darkgray
}
.row div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: lightgray
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

As can be seen the text doesn't goes out to the left of the viewport by 15px. Moreover both the rows are rendering without any gap in between. What happened to the `.row:after {display: table; content: " ";}`?

Please explain.

P.S: I don't know how the `@import url` at-rule work in SO editor.

Comment: If you want to look at the grid/row styles, check out the less: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/grid.less https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/grid.less https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins/grid-framework.less

Comment: @Doctus I don't know LESS language yet.

Comment: [This article](http://www.helloerik.com/the-subtle-magic-behind-why-the-bootstrap-3-grid-works) may be of interest to you.

Comment: @Doctus That article is good. It says thee is 15px padding to thee `.container`. So we need negative 15px margin on `.row`. But if we don't nest `row` inside `.container` then the contents or `.row` should span 15px outside the viewport, which is not happening.

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the entire thing in a div, and add `overflow: hidden;`, you get the following, which is the same as you have achieved above, without the container.

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.row div:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: rgba(168, 172, 176, 0.6);
}

.row div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(88, 86, 84, 0.6);
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 50px; 
  background: orange; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If however, you remove `overflow: hidden;`, you will see the following:

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css");

.row div:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: rgba(168, 172, 176, 0.6);
}

.row div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: rgba(88, 86, 84, 0.6);
}

#wrapper {
  margin: 50px; 
  background: orange; 
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You'll notice the rows sit outside of the beige container. This means the negative margin is being achieved, but it is being hidden by whatever default styles are applied to the `body`, and counteracted by the padding on the `.rows`, so it seems as if the margin is not working. You can observe this further using the development tools in your browser.

Comment: When `overflow: visible`(or auto) is set why do only the background of row extends outwards? Why don't the content start from the left-most of the row? It seems like there is some padding-left applied to row.

Comment: I believe that is what is happening, yes.

Comment: I found it in their css file. They've applied 15px padding to `.col-xs-*`, `.col-sm-*` and `.col-lg-*`. And can you also explain about the `.clearfix` applied to each row?

Comment: If the clearfix wasn't applied, then all of the rows (which are floated) would cause the parent to collapse.

Answer (score 0):

```
.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
 }
```

In this above case as you said it'll spread margin 15px to the left and right even if the row is added to the body tag.

```
 .row:before,
 .row:after,
 {
 display: table;
 content: " ";
  }


.row:after  
{
 clear: both;
}
```

In the second case its actually adding clearfix to the class row since class col's('col-lg-12') have float left property you've to add a clearfix for parent class.

Comment: Yes it is adding clearfix. But it doesn't use `visibility: none`, nor `height:0` to the clearfix.

Comment: @user31782   yes we dont need that properties.still it'll work.

Comment: We **need** them so that the `clearfix` don't occupy any space. But for some reason in bootstrap `.row` class it is still hidden without `visibility: hidden`.

Comment: @user31782   Its not hidden actually it doesn't have any height and width or its not a block level element at all. check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kcby4xmk/.

Comment: It **is** a block level element(note `display: table`) with `height: auto`. In your jsfiddle I think we have to import bootstrap.css.

Comment: @user31782 oh ok but it doesnt have any height right?

Comment: `height: auto` means take as much height as much needed to just fit the contents. Here the content is white space ` `. So the div should extend to one-line-height to encompass the ` `.

Comment: @user31782 I've imported bootstrap css. if theres a height to the pseoudo element it'll look like this https://jsfiddle.net/kcby4xmk/1/.

Answer (score 0):

```
.row:before, .row:after{
    display: table;
    content: " ";
    clear:both
}
```

Comment: He quoted the source code from bootstrap css, but added the `clear:both;` to both `:before` and `:after`, while in the bootstrap source the clear is only @ `:after`