# Is white space in content: " " ignored in clearfix hack?

Tags: html, css

I've been learning about the clearfix hack from csstricks. In the [*The Easy Clearing Methos*](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/float/). I found it behave unexpectidely. They suggested the code:

```
.clearfix:after { 
  content: "";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
```

First off I tried it as it is; it didn't clear nothing. Then I used one whitespace as the content(`content: " "`); nothing got cleared. Then I used a character as the content, `content: "H"`. `H` appeared above and below the floating div but didn't clear anything. Following are the codes I used following codes:

**`Content: ""`**

```css
 .rowx div:nth-of-type(even) {
   background-color: darkgray;
 }
 .rowx div:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background-color: lightgray;
 }
 .hack:after,
 .hack:before {
   content: "";
   clear: both;
   display: block;
 }
 .fitty {
   width: 20%;
   float: left;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="rowx">
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4 </div>
    <div class="fitty hack">.col-xs-4</div>
 
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4 </div>
  </div>
```

**`Content: " "`**

```css
 .rowx div:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: darkgray; 
}

.rowx div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: lightgray; 
}

.hack:after, .hack:before {
  content: " "; clear: both; display: block; 
}
.fitty {
  width: 20%; float: left;
}
```

```html
 <div class="rowx">
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4 </div>
    <div class="fitty hack">.col-xs-4</div>
 
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4 </div>
  </div>
```

**`Content: "H"`**

```css
 .rowx div:nth-of-type(even) {
   background-color: darkgray;
 }
 .rowx div:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background-color: lightgray;
 }
 .hack:after,
 .hack:before {
   content: "H";
   clear: both;
   display: block;
 }
 .fitty {
   width: 20%;
   float: left;
 }
```

```html
  <div class="rowx">
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4 </div>
    <div class="fitty hack">.col-xs-4</div>
 
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4 </div>
  </div>
```

**Question:**

- Why doesn't the clearfix hack clear floating elements?
- Is white space in `content: " "` completely ignored by the web browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why doesn't the clearfix hack clear floating elements?

Every float generates its own [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). An element (or pseudo-element) in one block formatting context [cannot clear floats in another block formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#flow-control). In your examples, there are essentially no floats for any of the clearfixes to clear, and the floats themselves aren't being cleared by anything. In other words, there is absolutely no clearance taking place in any of your examples.

> Is white space in `content: " "` completely ignored by the web browsers?

Whitespace in the `content` property is governed by the same whitespace processing rules in [section 16.6.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#white-space-model) of the CSS2.1 spec via the `white-space` property. A lone space in a block box is treated as insignificant and collapsed away, so the pseudo-elements effectively become empty even with `content: " "`, but you will see them if you set `white-space: pre`:

```css
 .rowx div:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: darkgray; 
}

.rowx div:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: lightgray; 
}

.hack:after, .hack:before {
  content: " "; clear: both; display: block; white-space: pre;
}
.fitty {
  width: 20%; float: left;
}
```

```html
 <div class="rowx">
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4 </div>
    <div class="fitty hack">.col-xs-4</div>
 
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4 </div>
  </div>
```

If you are trying to clear the floats, all you have to do is set `clear` on the floats themselves, the way the property was intended to be used. You don't need to resort to clearfix hacks.

Comment: Actually the whole confusion aroused from [my previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35886527/how-is-row-class-defined-in-bootstrap) In bootstrap they use clearfix on `.row` elements. I thought they use to clear floating `.col` elements But as you say, "_An element (or pseudo-element) in one block formatting context cannot clear floats in another block formatting context._", I am confused why they used clearfix on `.row` then?

Comment: I don't use Bootstrap, but the idea of a clearfix is to force a container to grow to the height of any floats inside it. The clearfix in that case does live in the same block formatting context as the floats it's clearing, which is why it works.

Comment: Ah thanks. In Bootstrap div with `.row` encompass floating divs with `col` class. They used clearfix on `.row` so that the container div could grow to the height of the floats inside.

Answer (score 0):

In addiction to the preceding answers, to make the trick work you have to create an addictional div with class .hack (see the snippet).

```css
.rowx div:nth-of-type(even) {
   background-color: darkgray;
 }
 .rowx div:nth-of-type(odd) {
   background-color: lightgray;
 }
 .hack:after,
 .hack:before {
   content: "";
   clear: both;
   display: block;
 }
 .fitty {
   width: 20%;
   float: left;
 }
```

```html
<div class="rowx">
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4 </div>
    <div class="fitty ">.col-xs-4</div>
<div class="hack"></div>
  <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4</div>
    <div class="fitty">.col-xs-4 </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Clearfix hack:**

1. Create a parent element
2. Add Floated elemets
3. Apply `clearfix` class to parent (stated in #1)

**Example:**

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.FL {
  float: left;
}
.FR {
  float: right;
}
.WithHack {
  background: steelblue;
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
.WithHack div {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
.WithOutHack {
  background: yellowgreen;
  padding: 20px;
   border: solid 1px black;
}
.WithOutHack div {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="WithHack clearfix">
    <div class="FL">I'm on Left</div>
    <div class="FR">I'm on Right</div>
  </div>
  <div class="WithOutHack">
    <div class="FL">I'm on Left</div>
    <div class="FR">I'm on Right</div>
  </div>
```

If you don't clear float then it won't be treated as part of Normal Document Flow. Floated elements behave in this manner only.

Comment: What is the benefit of such type of clearfix? Won't the green div be always cleared? The green div is block level element so it will always start from the bottom of previous elements.

Comment: As I mentioned, when elements are floated then they will be removed from Normal Document Flow, so need to explicitly clear them. It won't matter whether they are block-level or not. 
FYI, float elements become `Inline-block` element.

Comment: And why is padding working on float elements in the `withouthack` green div? Aren't the floating elements out of document flow?

Comment: padding isn't applied on green div, it's their behavior. (may be I'm wrong at this question)

Comment: I am saying that even if we don't use clearfix on the blue div the green div will always be cleared. So we do not need to use clearfix in such a situation.

Comment: whenever you want to use floated elements and want to place other elements below it then you need to wrap the floated element in a parent with hack, otherwise you won't get expected result.

Comment: Padding-top, -left and -right is applied to both green and blue divs. But padding-bottom is not.

Comment: not padding isn't applied. Can any expert comment on this? :D

Comment: We need not to wrap the floated element in a parent with hack when the subsequent elements are within anew div -- as is your green div. IT doesn't matter in such situation whether we use clearfix or not.

Comment: Remove the padding the container div will collapse. Change the padding  -- the floating elements will compress further.

Comment: That's what I said, if you have floated elements and want another element below it (same parent) then you need to clear floated elements. I guess, I'm clear now.

Comment: If we want to clear a floating element in the same parent then we can't do this by using clearfix on the parent. We'll have to use a div, just before that floating element which need to be cleared, with clear:both. In this case we won't use `content: " "`. I also figured out why we need clearfix on a parent div when the elements in other container div need to be cleared. Thanks for explaining.